# CSS: Making Horizontal scrollable Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a menu to my application screens. The menu will have the menu icons which are horizontal scroll-able one menu at a time when left or right arrow pressed. Based on the menu screen the menu should be scrolled to that menu icon for that menu screen.

Ex.:

---

```
 <   menu1     |  menu2  |   menu3   >
```

---

Say there are 6 menu icons and 3 are visible at a time. on press of right arrow, it should scroll one item at a time.

and if my screen is related to menu 4, the menu4 has to be positioned.

---

```
 <   menu4     |  menu5  |   menu6   >
```

---

And also each menu item should be clickable.

Please let me know, How I can achieve this.

**Update**
Have js for MouseOver

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var div = $('div.sc_menu'),
             ul = $('ul.sc_menu'),
             ulPadding = 15;
        var divWidth = div.width();
        div.css({ overflow: 'hidden' });
        var lastLi = ul.find('li:last-child');
        div.mousemove(function (e) {
            var ulWidth = lastLi[0].offsetLeft + lastLi.outerWidth() + ulPadding;

            var left = (e.pageX - div.offset().left) * (ulWidth - divWidth) / divWidth;
            div.scrollLeft(left);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**JSFiddle**

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/QdJvb/)

**Update3**

[image: Yahoo's Navigation]

**Update 4**

*This is dynamic menu retreived from db build with ul & li's. If there is more Li than screen width, I simply want an arrow to left & right side to scroll extra li's, if any.*

Comment: @Mohsen Please see Update, which I've for Hover effect. But Iwant it for onClick if there is any overflow.

Comment: if you can add JSFiddle 
will be great ..http://jsfiddle.net/ "to add javascript html css code"

Comment: Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdJvb/)

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I'm trying to do but I need it to work with touch. Any idea how to add touch to the scroll?

Answer (score 4):

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kzQFQ/49/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.right').click(function () {
    var position = $('.container').position();
    var r=position.left-$(window).width()
    $('.container').animate({
        'left': ''+r+'px'
    });
});    

$('.left').click(function () {
    var position = $('.container').position();
    var l=position.left+$(window).width()
    if(l<=0)
    {
    $('.container').animate({
        'left': ''+l+'px'
    });
    }
});    
});
```

Comment: Like you mentioned when clicked on left or right it scrolls.Using this idea you can create your required footer for your page.

Comment: I have added an update.If this is not what you are looking for take a screenshot.Add it to imgur with the area selected which you want.

Comment: I dont see anything on Yahoo's homepage that resembles what you're asking for here

Comment: Dear @Zword, Thanks for your help, but to clear can you see my original Q. where i post < Menu1 | menu2 >. This is dynamic menu retreived from db build with ul & li's. If there is more Li than screen width, I simply want an arrow to left & right side to scroll extra li's, if any. is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

Good article about horizontal scrollable menu [here](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/23/scroll-overflow-menu/)

And [DEMO](http://darbybrown.com/menu/#) (Note: Reduce the size of the browser)

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail, but I exactly needed what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

hop this should be help you see link

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

see **Non-Image Content** at the last of page

see this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/vac9x/1/

Comment: Dear @Aliana, How do I handle arrow's visibility on overflow?

Comment: I want arrows on side conditionally if any overflow occurred.